# Load the CSV file in to the content Database with collection using corb

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-corb

I have a CSV file in my local folder. I want to load that file into MarkLogic DB using CoRB into a specified Collection. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to configure your job to use the [**URIS-FILE**](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#URIS-FILE) option pointing to your CSV. CORB will read the file and send each of the lines from the CSV to the configured [**PROCESS-MODULE**](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#PROCESS-MODULE) as the `$URI` value to be processed.

The properties file would look something like this:

```
# how to connect to to the XCC server
XCC-CONNECTION-URI=xcc://user:password@localhost:8202/
# path to the CSV file to be processed
URIS-FILE=input-uris.csv 
# the module that will process and save each CSV row
PROCESS-MODULE=save-row.xqy|ADHOC
# how many threads to use to execute process modules
THREAD-COUNT=10
```

In your process module, you would need to declare an external variable called `$URIS`, and then tokenize on your CSV row by the delimiter and process the columns of data. Invoke [`xdmp:document-insert()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-insert) to insert the document and specify the collection(s) that you want the document to be in:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare variable $URI as xs:string external;

let $columns := fn:tokenize($URI, ",\s?")
(: assuming that the first column has a unique value to be used for the URI :)
let $uri := $columns[1]
(:do whatever processing you would need to generate the document from CSV columns :)
let $content := $columns[2] 
return 
  xdmp:document-insert($uri,
    $content, 
    map:map() => map:with("collections", "mySpecialCollection")
  )
```

***Note:*** the signature for xdmp:document-insert() has recently changed. You now specify `xdmp:document-insert` options, such as permissions and collections, in either a map or an options element in the third parameter. In prior MarkLogic versions, permissions and collections were the third and fourth parameters. Adjust the call to `xdmp:document-insert()` according to the version of MarkLogic that you are using (there is a dropdown on the top left side of the documentation to select your version).